# multiple column query in sharepoint default search

Tags: search, search-results

How can I query against multiple fields in sharepoint default search?

[image]

I used `Department:'ADB'` and it worked, now I want to add few more columns like

**Department:'ADB' & Title:'Mr' & Division:"ASN"**

But its not working

Answer (score 1):

You can use + instead of & it looks like below. make sure Department,Division are created as Managed property

`Department:ADB+Title:Mr+Division:ASN`

I tries like this it worked for me

`path:"https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/Lists/Employee"+Title:Title1+Title:Title2`

you can also try by keeping filter on refiners. For this you need to attach
crawl property of Department field to RefinableString01 and  crawl property of Division field to RefinableString02.

`refinementfilters='and(RefinableString01:equals("ADB"),RefinableString02:equals("ASN"))`

use the below search query tool to develop your query to filter on multiple managed properties/fields

http://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/

Comment: I created a managed property for a column, but its not working when I try with that

Comment: You need to run the full crawl after creating the managed property

Comment: yeah I did that
I am not sure if the managed property is mapped to the column in the list I am looking for
is there a way to check that?

Comment: Check in crawl properties with that name, it will create like this ows_Department, for the Managed property "Department" you should map the crawl property "ows_Department"

Comment: did you try this in default search box? Because I am not getting results if I use + 
It works when I search for one column though

Comment: yes. Why cannot you try with Refiners filter if that one is not working for you
in managed property search for `Refinablestring01` and map crwal property `Ows_Department` to it same way for `Division` also
and try this `refinementfilters='and(RefinableString01:equals("ADB"),RefinableString02:equals("ASN"))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55812/discussion-between-vignesh-and-suresh-bolineni).